# Поменять параметры top и left в css через js

Tags: javascript, css

Как поменять параметры top,left у класса bounce через js?

```
.bounce { // класс который нужно поменять
      position: absolute; 
top: 380px; // вверх низ
left:450px;// право лево
display: none;// выключено отображение 
}












 document.getElementsByClassName('bounce')[0].style.top = '0'; // пытаюсь поменять top на 0
 document.getElementsByClassName('bounce)[0].style.left = '0'; // пытаюсь пометь left на 0
     document.getElementsByClassName('bounce')[0].style.display = 'block'; // включаем отображение
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function move() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('bounce')[0].style.top = '0px';
  document.getElementsByClassName('bounce')[0].style.left = '0px';
  document.getElementsByClassName('bounce')[0].style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.bounce {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
  display: none; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<button onclick="move()">Click</button>
<div class="bounce"></div>
```